# 'Literally' non-literally

Tags: historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, lexical-semantics

There has been a recent popularization over the questionable use of the word 'literally' as an intensifier rather than as a marker of non-figurative, especially since it seems to be used non-literally by [well-respected modern authors](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3007). There is a lot of evidence that it has been used non-literally literally [for centuries](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3012).

"Literal", in English, is primarily used to imply 'exactly as spoken/written' so that when something is said that sounds like hyperbole, it will be taken as truthful rather than exaggerated.

But that situation also is semantically ambiguous in that things could seem truly exaggerated. And then, if one didn't know otherwise, the term 'literally' could be understood as an intensifier, and therefore taken in a non-literal manner.

It seems to me that there is nothing special about 'literal' in English that it should be the only one to have such ambiguity leading to semantic drift.

- The Romance languages all have a similar sounding word with base 'literal-' and it is just as opaque (no conscious implication of 'verbatim' or 'as written/read').
- The Germanic languages all have variants of 'buchstäblich' or 'wörtlich' which sound a little closer to 'word for word'.
- Similarly, Slavic uses cognates of either 'bukvalno' or 'doslownie'
- Chinese has 字面, meaning (closely) 'by character'. This meaning seems transparent to me (and therefore unlikely to lead to drift).

But as figurative meanings don't even need phonetic changes to help them become figurative, I wonder if there are similar figurative uses of the word or phrase corresponding to 'literal' in other languages.

Is there any evidence that the corresponding terms for 'literal' in non-English languages have similar figurative uses?

Comment: Esperantists whose native language is other than English would be the ideal respondents to this question. This question, posed in Esperanto, would be ideal for the forum section of the "LERNU!" website: https://lernu.net/eo/forumo

Comment: @EsperantoSpeaker1 What makes esperanto speakers so special in this regard more so than others?

Comment: Such questions, asking for input from members of other language groups, are ideal for an IAL, and Esperanto is the IAL with the most momentum.

Comment: @EsperantoSpeaker1 As interesting as that is, that's not a particularly convincing argument. How would the simple existence of an international auxiliary language say _anything_ about metaphorical uses of terms in languages, especially ones that talk about concepts related to metaphor (or rather the lack thereof).

Comment: You seem to be picking up the wrong end of the stick, maybe because this is totally new terrain for you. So: by means of an IAL you could reach otherwise unreachable people from other language groups who could share with you, via the IAL, what how their languages deal with metaphor.

Comment: OK, I'll bite. What's so special about Esperanto? Why not Hebrew? Or Toki Pona? I think the only possible relevance of Esperanto is examples of non-literal use of the corresponding term for 'literal' _or_ some explanation as to why it would be unlikely to appear non-literally (of course, such an explanation probably works equally well for any language where meaning is ... used).

Comment: I have cross posted this to [German.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36718/w%C3%B6rtlich-unw%C3%B6rtlich) where I got a positive answer. I will attempt at other language specific sites.